# AddEventListener click event not woorking

Tags: javascript

so i am trying to make a game for a proyect that shows a 'next' button . My code seems to not work out as I add the event listener to a variable. The console tells me that even the variable is null and on the inspector the event tag doesnt appear. I dont seem to know what the problem is.

```js
var section = document.querySelector('seccion');
var container = document.querySelector('container');
var text = document.querySelector('text');
var optionButtons = document.querySelector('option-buttons')
const button = document.getElementById('next');

var siguiente = button.addEventListener('click', next, true);

var next = function() {
    var aparece = alert('funciona')
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>text Adventure</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DotGothic16&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon"> 
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    
    <section id="seccion">    
    <div class="container">
        <div id="text">text</div>
        <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
        <button id='next' class="btn">Siguiente</button>            
        </div>
    </section>    
    
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="app.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `next` is `undefined` when you call `addEventListener`. Change the order of your code so you define it **before** you use it.

Comment: Thank you! it worked. I have seen some teachers calling the function after the eventlistener and it worked for them. But this helped me a lot. Than you again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Your HTML is invalid

   The div with the class 'container' needs to be closed inside the section tag, your's is outside of it.
   To prevent this kind of mistakes I recommend some kind of HTML formatter like [this one](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html).
2. In your JavaScript you use a function before it's defined.
   In this case it is the next function. Define it before adding it to the EventListener like this:

```
function next() {
    var aparece = alert('funciona')
}

var siguiente = button.addEventListener('click', next, true);
```

Comment: I wonder where that minus point comes from. This is the correct answer

Answer (score -2):

You need to change variable to function to use power of javascript hoisting or change order of the code:

```js
var section = document.querySelector('seccion');
var container = document.querySelector('container');
var text = document.querySelector('text');
var optionButtons = document.querySelector('option-buttons')
const button = document.getElementById('next');

var siguiente = button.addEventListener('click', next, true);

function next() {
    var aparece = alert('funciona')
};
```

or

```js
var section = document.querySelector('seccion');
var container = document.querySelector('container');
var text = document.querySelector('text');
var optionButtons = document.querySelector('option-buttons')
const button = document.getElementById('next');

var next = function() {
    var aparece = alert('funciona')
};

var siguiente = button.addEventListener('click', next, true);
```